# Ubuntu 12.10 update-manager wants to remove Groovy

Tags: ros, ubuntu, groovy-beta

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am using Ubuntu 12.10 and just installed ros-groovy-desktop-full. When I run Ubuntus update-manager it says it has to do an partial upgrade and wants to remove ros-groovy-desktop-full (and upgrade some ros-groovy packages). Any idea what is going on? Is it just my computers problem? I don't dare to upgrade in fear of removing the whole ROS installation...
Cheers,
Oier

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48844/ubuntu-12.10-update-manager-wants-to-remove-groovy/) by [Oier](https://answers.ros.org/users/3642/oier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 145 on 2012-11-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Oier](https://answers.ros.org/users/3642/oier/) on 2012-11-26**:
I already had boost 1.49. It seems that the package ros-groovy-desktop-full is now missing on the repository. On the installations instructions it says the following: "Desktop-Full Install: (Recommended) Not available in beta 1: ROS, rqt, rviz, robot-generic libraries, 2D/3D simulators, navigation "

**Comment by [Oier](https://answers.ros.org/users/3642/oier/) on 2012-12-02**:
Well, after removing ros-groovy-desktop-full (can't reinstall it since it is not available in the repo), now the packet manager suddenly wants to remove the following packages: ros-groovy-camera-calibration, ros-groovy-cv-bridge, ros-groovy-depth-image-proc etc. but they still exist in the repo...

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-12-10**:
There's a conflict somewhere up the dependency tree.  Unfortunately apt doesn't provide many good error messages.  You'll probably have to manually walk up the tree deleting things until you find the one that conflicts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is likely a boost dependency issue. If you're like me, you updated from 12.04 to 12.10, and just installed groovy. Check your boost version. If you have 1.46, you'll need 1.49 for groovy. So, I recommend you let the package manager remove it, and install groovy again after the update. Worked for me!

Best of luck! - Hunter A.

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2012-11-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1